# RDS Webpage Display Delays

Tags: windows-server-2012, internet-explorer, remote-desktop-services

I have built a Windows Server 2012 with RDS for testing purposes.

When logged on as any user (Administrator or standard user), opening multiple Internet Explorer (or even Firefox) pages experience a very long delay in loading. What I mean with that is I open another tab (with a webpage link), and there a multiple second delay in the Internet Explorer program "hanging". After that time, it loads correctly.

All other programs on the server operate fine (Word, Excel, Outloook, etc), it is just in web browser programs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that connects are via MSTSC v8.0 on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue - it was a strange one that I should have thought of much sooner...

I was testing some Wyse TCX software and after removing it - everything came good...